# How to start java process which runs just for an hour in a day in kunernetes

Tags: kubernetes

We have a java process which runs for an hour every day and generates a files. i am looking for a k8s solution for this.

job runs at 10 AM every day and it generates a file by 11 AM.
after this we need to destroy the deployment.
the job is expected to start again tomorrow at 10 AM.

can someone help in achieving this

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) which uses a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) rather than a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).